# How troubleshoot black screen issue on iPhone device?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Sometimes, When I added a new UI component or even just update the auto layout value to storyboard, the device went to a black screen state like this:

[image]

What does this meaning? What happened on this situation? Is there any log or tips to troubleshoot these kind of cases?

This is the `View UI Hierarchy`:, there are only two UI Window.

[image]

This is the normal one.

[image]

What I can do for now is to revert my work to previous state and `trial and error`. It's time consuming and inefficient.

**Update:**

Add my interface builder screenshot:

[image]

Update the screencast:

[image]

Comment: You could use Visual Debug Hierarchy to help you understand what are the object displayed.

Comment: Typically, a black screen is the view behind your window. Check that your auto layout is correct and that you haven't disconnected some views. A screenshot of your IB would also be very helpful.

Comment: @Dominic, Thanks, I added it. For example, When I modified `logout` button in the 3rd view controller, update the constrains to move it to another position could cause black screen issue. Any idea ?

Comment: Are you setting constraint priorities that are pushing views around?

Comment: No, I all use default value: 1000.

Comment: OK, I'm at a loss without the source code. Can you set something up on GitHub?

Comment: @Dominic I uploaded it to here:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13860657/sip.ios.zip . I will have black screen on iPhone 6 simulator.

Comment: The project doesn't build properly for me. I've done the pod install but there seem to be some dependencies that I don't have connections for (possibly you have compiled some libraries somewhere?)... sorry I'm out of time on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I seems that the login button on the first page had a unknown issue. I removed the login button and added it back again. No problem anymore.